# Почему не подключается файл со стилями к jsp?

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp

Приложение с поддержкой spring-mvc
Вот как я его подключаю:

```
<head>
    <title>Закладки</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/css/styles.css">
</head>
```

Каталог проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался также подключить стили из resources но из-за того, что web-папка не лежит в src их вообще не видно оттуда. Если можно указать папку с ресурсами в spring-mvc, то подскажите как? Я пытался указать ресурсы через `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`, но значение `location` выделяется красным и все, опять же из-за расположения WEB-INF.

Comment: вы хоть в какой jsp подключаете?

Comment: Очевидно, что такого пути `href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/css/styles.css"` быть не может ! Может быть например такой `href="css/styles.css"`. Собери варник и посмотри куда твои ресурсы кладутся (может и не кладутся вовсе)

Comment: @michael_best, в bookmarks.

Comment: @keekkenen, `href="css/styles.css"` я сначала так и написал, но мне компилер начал подчеркивать. Такой путь - `href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/css/styles.css"`(я же беру как бы корень web-папки и прописываю абсолютный путь) не подчеркивает, но стили не подключаются.  Я прописывал относительный путь от bookmarks `../css/styles.css`, но стили так же не подключались, но компилятор пропускал

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось нормально подключить стили вот таким способом:

```
<style> 
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/styles.css"%> 
</style>
```

Но все-таки меня интересует почему вот так они не подключаются:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
```

И почему в этой строке -`href="../css/styles.css"` прописывать необходимо путь относительно jsp страницы bookmarks.jsp